# JavaScript Read text file returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code which should read the current text file's contents and make a new line and write a new sentence in that line, it writes it but the line before that is just undefined.

```js
const data = msg.author.tag + " bejelentkezett a bottal. " + d.toLocaleTimeString();
             const currenttext = fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
                fs.writeFile('output.txt', currenttext + '\n' + data, (err) => {
                      
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

readFile does not return anything. Instead you will be given the contents in your callback in the variable you named contents.

So change

```
fs.writeFile('output.txt', currenttext + '\n' + data, (err) => {
```

to

```
fs.writeFile('output.txt', contents+ '\n' + data, (err) => {
```

As a side note your error handling is a mess. Throwing an error from within a callback just leads to losing the error.  Consider using the promise api with async/await instead to simplify your code or update your callbacks. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api